# Appending SVG Elements in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Going through D3.js tutorials, I see two different conventions, and I am not sure what the difference is because they both product the same code:

1)

```
var chart = d3.select("body")
              .append("svg:svg")  
              .attr("class", "chart")
              .attr("width", w * data.length - 1)
              .attr("height", h);

    chart.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg:rect")
```

2)

```
var chart = d3.select("body")
              .append("svg")  
              .attr("class", "chart")
              .attr("width", w * data.length - 1)
              .attr("height", h);

    chart.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
```

Can someone explain the difference between append("svg") and append("svg:svg") and why I would use one or the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `svg:` part specifies the name space for the element that comes after it, i.e. an `svg` element in the `svg` namespace. It was advisable to specify this in older versions of d3 as it might be interpreted incorrectly otherwise, but it is not necessary to do so in recent versions.